# MySQL Count, Melt(Reshaping) Variable

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a data set about flights, and I am interested to find out the pairs of passenger who took the same flight are sitting in the same row. Assuming that only Row is unique among all flights, which mean if row 1 is being occupied in flight number 10, then it cannot be appeared in flight 11.

ie. look below into the sample data.

However, if there are 3 people took the same flight sitting on the same row, then I want to ignore them, so that I am only counting for pairs, not 3 people.

Here's the sample data:

```
Passenger   Flight_Number   Row
1             10            1
2             10            1
3             10            3
4             11            5
1             11            5
2             11            6
3             11            7
1             12            2
2             12            2
3             12            2
```

Codes are given:

```
CREATE TABLE flight
(
    Passenger INT NOT NULL,
    Flight_Number INT NOT NULL,
    Row_Number INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO flight 
VALUES(1, 10, 1),(2, 10, 1),(3, 10, 3),
      (4, 11, 5),(1, 11, 5),(2, 11, 6),
      (3, 11, 7),(1, 12, 2),(2, 12, 2),
      (3, 12, 2);
```

What I want is:

```
Flight_Number   Row Passenger_A Passenger_B
10               1         1             2
11               5         4             1
```

Special notes in here, because Flight number 12 has 3 passengers sitting in the same row, thus we ignore it.

So far, my thoughts are:

```
SELECT Passenger, Flight_Number, Row_Count 
FROM flight RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT Row, COUNT(*) AS Row_Count FROM flight GROUP BY Row) AS Count
WHERE Row_Count = 2  AND...
```

Any helps on how I may continue this? ie. How to get Passenger_A and Passenger_B and etc?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.Flight_Number,a.Row_Number,
  f1.Passenger as Passenger_A,
  f2.Passenger as Passenger_B
FROM (
  select Flight_Number,Row_Number from flight 
  group by Flight_Number,Row_Number having count(*)=2
  ) a
join flight f1 
  on (f1.Flight_Number=a.Flight_Number and f1.Row_Number=a.Row_Number)
join flight f2 
  on (f2.Flight_Number=a.Flight_Number and f2.Row_Number=a.Row_Number)
where f1.Passenger>f2.Passenger
```

The last condition eliminates duplicate pairs as well as coupling a passenger with himself.

Comment: Hi Geomagas, thank you for your input. And you also pointed out the problem with the last condition.. :(  I'm going to see if I can find a solution to fix it.  But thanks though, greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was referring to (explaining) the `where` clause of _my_ query. There's no problem, results appear as expected. No?

Comment: It works mostly, however for Passenger_B, it gives 1,1 for both flight number 10, 11. Where it was supposed to be 2,1 for Passenger_B.

Comment: What do you mean? It gives (2,1) for flight#10 and (4,1) for flight#11. That's correct, considering there's no requirement in your question for the ordering of passengers in the couples (ie which gets to be A and wich B).

Comment: My apology, I have been doing this all night long, it must been the fact that I was super tired, so that I read the wrong stuff.. :(

Comment: A BIG THANKS to YOU.  :)